# How to make this alternative definition of Maybe work?

Tags: haskell, option-type

I hvae just invended the following alternative definition of `Maybe`:

```
type Maybe' a = forall b. (b -> (a -> b) -> b)

just :: a -> Maybe' a
just a = \d f -> f a

nothing :: Maybe' a
nothing = const

bind :: Maybe' a -> (a -> Maybe' b) -> Maybe' b
bind ma f = ma nothing (\a -> f a)
```

The problem is I can't add the following instance declaration

```
instance Monad (Maybe') where
    return = just
    a >>= f = bind a f
```

The error message is :

```
Type synonym Maybe' should have 1 argument, but has been given none
```

Are there any way to fix?

Comment: Ahem, sorry to be that pedant but you haven't invented a new Maybe, you've rediscovered its **Church encoding** - see here for example - https://gist.github.com/rampion/2176199

Comment: I came up with same answer independently by googling "Church encoding Maybe" lol. I did not steal your answer.

Comment: A funny fact: viewed as a proposition, your `Maybe(A)` is `FALSE -> NOT(NOT(A))`, which is classically equivalent to `TRUE OR A` — the disjunction of a unit type `()` and type `A`.

Comment: @stephentetley After reading http://ia700401.us.archive.org/8/items/TheoreticalFoundationsForPracticaltotallyFunctionalProgramming/33429551_PHD_totalthesis.pdf I consider the better name of this `Maybe'` is **Platonic combinator**, and **Church encoding** is only special cases of it.

Comment: @EarthEngine Keep in mind that Church encoding is named after Alonzo Church who literally invented lambda calculus.  This is why Church encoding is the common name for this approach, even though some other approaches sometimes subsume it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only make it an instance of `Monad` if you wrap it in a `newtype`.  You also have to use the `PolymorphicComponents` extension (a weaker form of `RankNTypes`) to universally quantify the `b`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolymorphicComponents #-}

newtype Maybe' a = Maybe' { unMaybe' :: forall b. (b -> (a -> b) -> b) }

just :: a -> Maybe' a
just a = Maybe' (\d f -> f a)

nothing :: Maybe' a
nothing = Maybe' const

bind :: Maybe' a -> (a -> Maybe' b) -> Maybe' b
bind ma f = Maybe' (unMaybe' ma const (\a -> unMaybe' (f a)))

instance Monad Maybe' where
    return = just
    (>>=)  = bind
```

The reason you need a newtype is that Haskell type synonyms do not "stick".  When Haskell tries to match the type signature of `Maybe'` without the newtype against the `Monad` type class, it does not see the `Maybe'` at all and instead sees the raw underlying function type.

Haskell uses "principal types" to ensure that every type has a normal form.  The normal form of the underlying function is:

```
(->) b ((->) ((->) a b) b)
```

Type synonyms do not change the normal form of a type, but newtypes do.  Specifically, the `newtype` in this case is rearranging the type so that the normal form now has the `a` as the very last type parameter like the `Monad` instance requires.

Comment: `PolymorphicComponents` isn't really weaker than `RankNTypes`, at least in GHC (in fact they're two names for the same extension -- `Rank2Types` is another name for it. In the past they were treated differently). Note that with this newtype, the constructor `Maybe'` has a rank-2 type.

Comment: +1. However this looks a little bit ugly because of those `Maybe'` and `unMaybe'`s. Are there any good reason that it is not allowed? Can you explain a little bit? Also, I am using `RankNTypes` and `ExistentialQuantification` any way.

Comment: @EarthEngine I don't know exactly how to explain this well, but I updated my answer to give my best attempt of explaining why you need the newtype.

Comment: @shachaf Thanks!  I never knew that.  I'll use `RankNTypes` from now on.

Comment: Just interesting to note: The reducing function `maybe : b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b` is after rearranging the same as unMaybe'.  This is rather helpful for finding the church encoding. It works for either and pairs too.

Answer (score 6):

Type synonyms are not types. With `newtype` you get a `* -> *` type, and with type synonyms you don't. So your question is now reduced to why type synonyms are not first class.

The answer is probably because first class synonyms would create too many ambiguities and make type inference impossible in simple cases.

```
type First a b = (a, b)
type Second a b = (b, a)
type Both a = (a, a)
```

If we can define `Functor (First a)`, `Functor (Second a)` and `Functor (Both a)` instances, then `fmap (+1) (2, 3)` would be ambigous.

Your invention, BTW, is called [Church encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding). It's possible to Church-encode anything. See https://gist.github.com/rampion/2176199 for implementation of few Church encodings in Haskell (pairs, Maybe and lists).

Answer (score 1):

Type synonyms cannot be partially applied.

A type synonym is just a short hand to help the programmer, not something that actually exists as something the Haskell language can talk about. The only way Haskell can deal with a type synonym is by "looking through" it to see the type on the right hand side. The parameters just give you a sort of "macro language".

So `Maybe' a` is exactly equivalent to `forall b. (b -> (a -> b) -> b)`. It behaves just as if you'd written `forall b. (b -> (a -> b) -> b)` instead. But what is `Maybe'` on its own without an argument then? Haskell can't deal with it as `Maybe'`, it would have to replace it with something else. But what? If it meant anything, it would have to be something like `\a ~> (forall b. (b -> (a -> b) -> b)`, where I'm using `\a ~> ...` as pseudo-syntax for a type-level lambda; an arbitrary function from a type to another type. The reason I had to make up syntax for that is because Haskell has no syntax for this, and the reason it has no syntax is because it cannot handle fully general type-level functions.

I'm not certain whether supporting arbitrary type-level lambdas (type constructors and type families are effectively very restricted forms of this) would be actually impossible, but it's certainly very difficult. So type synonyms can't be partially applied.

To get something that can made an instance of `Monad` (which needs something that can be applied to a type to make a type - something of kind `* -> *`), you need to use `data` or `newtype` to create a type constructor. A type synonym can't be used for this purpose.